# Handling properties as a dimension

Tags: ssas, data-modeling, olap-cube, dimension, fact

Sample are collected from patients. Depending upon the type of the sample, samples could have different properties/attributes. There is a list of 5 properties/attributes which are standard across all samples, but they can have 2 dynamic properties. These properties/attributes vary for sample types. I am trying to model this scenario.

Following is what i was thinking from a design perspective

Sample Dimension 
Sample Fact (related to Sample Dimension table)

I have also created a table called Sample Properties which has a single row for a property of the sample.

Sample Fact and Dimension are 1 to 1. Where as Sample Dimension to Sample Properties is 1 to many.

I am really confused how can i model this scenario, so that if any one wants to look at sample properties they can do that. The sample properties won't be analyzed but will be just looked at.

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me with the design of the cube. If any more detail is needed please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "sample properties won't be analyzed but will be just looked at"?